# Mysql insert only if limit has not been reached

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I hope I have got the title right as I don't really know how to word this!!

Here's the background...

I have a app inserting data to a db. The db holds a date field and data field (there are others but for simplicity these two are the only ones needed). There can only be 8 entries on the same date, no more. In normal operation this is not really an issue but twice a month the database gets hit hard towards the end of the day.

The way I currently do it, is to query how many records there are for a date. If that's less than 9 I insert the data.

It has never happened yet but my concern is that request A comes in and checks the DB and finds there are 7 records. OK to insert. But before A can insert, request B comes in and finds only 7 records. OK to insert. But that would then enter 9 records on one date. This can't happen.

I think there are two solutions to this but would like to know A, if I'm right at all! or B is there a better solution.

I think...

A) I could do it in a transaction. However, would I still no encounter the same problem? As far as I am aware as long as no queries in a transaction fail then it runs anyway.

or

B) Use a stored procedure to check first then insert. I have had very little experience with stored procedures so I must admit I have no idea what I'm talking about here!

Alternatively, is there a way to get a single query to check first if there is less than 9 entries??

Many Thanks in advance,

Gavin

Comment: Perhaps you could consider locking the table before each new insert?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are afraid of that someone would insert a new record before other one insert it even in the million second?

I have this question too, so I just searched something for you, you can do this with two ways:

For example if you have a table which named **`date_table`** and it looks like:

```
date_field
----------
1998-07-13
1992-03-23
1998-09-17
1994-02-30
```

---

**A) Count the rows, then insert it when it's under 8 rows. (Using PHP and MySQL)**

First, get how many rows are there by this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num FROM date_table WHERE date_field = '1998-07-13'
```

so you'll get a **`Num`** field which told you how many rows were **`1998-07-13`**,

then using PHP to prevent user insert the same date when it's equal 8 by:

```
<?php if($DB['Num'] >= 8) exit('Sorry, no more same value'); ?>
```

otherwise insert the row.

---

Or you don't trust PHP, or you think someone would insert the row more earlier than 1 million second

**B) Insert it when it's only under 8 rows were same with only one query:**

```
INSERT INTO date_table (date_field) 
     SELECT '1998-07-13' 
     FROM dual 
     WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM date_table WHERE date_field = '1998-07-13') < 9;
```

**BEWARE: `dual` is a mysql system table, so you don't need to create it**

If you don't understand how the above query works:

```
insert into TABLE_NAME (TABLE_FIELD) 
     select VALUE_YOU_WANT_TO_INSERT
     from dual 
     where (select count(*) 
            from TABLE_NAME 
            where THE_FIELD_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK = '1998-07-13'
           ) < LESS_THEN_HOW_MUCH;
```

---

**EDIT**: add more fields change the following lines:

```
INSERT INTO date_table (field1, field2, field3) 
     SELECT value1, value2, value3
```

Comment: Yami, I like the idea of answer B. I struggling now with how to add other fields to this query?

Comment: Edited, hope you understand

Comment: Doesn't this seem more complicated than simply locking the table to make sure to avoid collisions/the insertion of a 9th value?

Comment: I agreed with you, locking table could be more secure, but I think every query has its own priority, anyway, I do really believe you're right

Comment: I must admit, trying to implement this is getting a bit tedious!! I think your right Mawg, locking the table for the write will probably be the best option.

Comment: which engine are you using in MySQL?

Comment: The second version actually does locking in innodb. Also causes deadlocks so you would have to check if the insert was successfull and retry if a deadlock occured.