# Limit of uploading documents

Tags: php, mysql

How to limit uploading documents!

For example:- If the database already has 5 entries, it should not take the 6th entry. And show **You can only have 5 documents**

My Code:-

```
<?php

    error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); // avoid notice

    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];// user name
        $userjob = $_POST['user_job'];// user email

        $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];


        if(empty($username)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Name.";
        }
        else if(empty($userjob)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Description.";
        }
        else if(empty($imgFile)){
            $errMSG = "Please Select Image File.";
        }
        else
        {
            $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory

            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

            // valid image extensions
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'txt'); // valid extensions

            // rename uploading image
            $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

            // allow valid image file formats
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
                // Check file size
                if($imgSize < 10000000)             {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                }
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, this file is not allowed.";       
            }
        }


        // if no error occured, continue ....
        if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userProfession,userPic) VALUES(:uname, :ujob, :upic)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':uname',$username);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ujob',$userjob);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
                header("refresh:1;index.php"); // redirects image view page after 1 seconds.
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

So, what should I add that give my output!

I want only 5 documents in my database. If user tries to add more than 5 documents, the error should be shown.

Comment: Fetch # of rows in your table prior to inserting in your database. See here for an example how do grab it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144741/count-number-of-rows-in-table-using-php

Comment: Can you please input the code in my code shown above. Actually, I am confused where to add!

Comment: Add it before `$stmt = $DB_con->prepare`. You will get `$row['cc']` as #. Then check if  `$row['cc']` < 5. If so, execute the rest of your script, otherwise abort.

Comment: How & What to add exactly, please edit my code and answer it!

Comment: Rndus2r's approach has received an upvote, but it suffers from a race condition. All you need is an insert

Comment: @Strawberry what to insert?

Comment: @Strawberry Where is the race condition?

Comment: @rndus2r How & What to add exactly, please edit my code and answer it!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26448803/8461611 I guess that would be Strawberry's approach or look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814601/mysql-insert-only-if-limit-has-not-been-reached

Comment: Please answer my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 vote to [aidinMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3398171/aidinmc)

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138084/limit-of-uploading-documents/46138519#46138519) of [aidinMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3398171/aidinmc) partially solves your question.

There are two small mistakes in [aidinMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3398171/aidinmc) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138084/limit-of-uploading-documents/46138519#46138519)

> 1) Strike of `:` from `else:`

```
  }
else
    $errMSG = "You already insert 5 rows";
endif;
```

> 2) Change `if($count >= 5)` to `if($count < 5)`

```
$count = $data[0]['rows'];
if($count < 5)
{
```

After changing these two errors [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138084/limit-of-uploading-documents/46138519#46138519) of [aidinMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3398171/aidinmc) will work! But after seeing your comments especially [Limit of uploading documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138084/limit-of-uploading-documents/46138519#comment79239269_46138519) & [Limit of uploading documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138084/limit-of-uploading-documents/46138519#comment79239394_46138519) it will not give the result as you want.

So what you want is here:-

```
<?php
error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); // avoid notice
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];// user name
        $userjob = $_POST['user_job'];// user email

        $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];


        if(empty($username)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Name.";
        }
        else if(empty($userjob)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Description.";
        }
        else if(empty($imgFile)){
            $errMSG = "Please Select Image File.";
        }
        else
        {
            $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory

            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

            // valid image extensions
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'txt'); // valid extensions

            // rename uploading image
            $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

            // allow valid image file formats
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
                // Check file size
                if($imgSize < 10000000)             {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                }
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, this file is not allowed.";       
            }
        }


        // if no error occured, continue ....
        if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userProfession,userPic) VALUES(:uname, :ujob, :upic)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':uname',$username);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ujob',$userjob);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);
$data = $DB_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows FROM tbl_users WHERE 1")->fetchall();
$count = $data[0]['rows'];
if($count < 5)
{
            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
                header("refresh:1;index.php"); // redirects image view page after 1 seconds.
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
            }
        }
        else
{
    $errMSG = "You already insert 5 rows";
}
    }
}

?>
```

I have just edited placement of codes [Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138084/limit-of-uploading-documents/46138519#46138519) by [aidinMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3398171/aidinmc) and fixed some bugs in [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138084/limit-of-uploading-documents/46138519#46138519) of [aidinMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3398171/aidinmc).

Hope this will work.

Comment: Till now it's working exactly as I want! But if there are any mistakes in future you may be mentioned! Thank You

Comment: Will be happy to help you in future too.

Comment: @ChiragJain ✓✓✓

Comment: @BabaluPandey Again, this suffers from the race condition fault.

Answer (score 1):

First count `tbl_users` data and check if rows smaller than 5 , insert new data:

```
$errMSG = "";
error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); // avoid notice
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
$continue = true;
$data = $DB_con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows FROM tbl_users WHERE 1")->fetchall();
$count = $data[0]['rows'];
if($count >= 5)
    $continue = false;
if($continue):
    if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];// user name
        $userjob = $_POST['user_job'];// user email

        $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];


        if(empty($username)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Name.";
        }
        else if(empty($userjob)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Description.";
        }
        else if(empty($imgFile)){
            $errMSG = "Please Select Image File.";
        }
        else
        {
            $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory

            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

            // valid image extensions
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'txt'); // valid extensions

            // rename uploading image
            $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

            // allow valid image file formats
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
                // Check file size
                if($imgSize < 10000000)             {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                }
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, this file is not allowed.";       
            }
        }


        // if no error occured, continue ....
        if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userProfession,userPic) VALUES(:uname, :ujob, :upic)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':uname',$username);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ujob',$userjob);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
                header("refresh:1;index.php"); // redirects image view page after 1 seconds.
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
            }
        }
    }
else:
    $errMSG = "You already insert 5 rows";
endif;
```

Comment: 1st error:- It says **You already insert 5 rows** before inserting anything. but there are only 3

Comment: 2nd error:- If all 5 rows are there then it doesn't take the 6th row. Good. But it does not show the message:- **You already insert 5 rows**

Comment: @BabaluPandey Are you sure you have only 3 rows in table? maybe you want to count rows by username , in this state you should change query string like this:`"SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows FROM tbl_users WHERE userName='$_POST[user_name]'"`

Comment: @BabaluPandey With this data if you are using `SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows FROM tbl_users WHERE 1` query, you should get **You already insert 5 rows** error, Are you get this error?

Comment: Seems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138084/limit-of-uploading-documents/46139155#46139155 to be working as I want. Thank you for helping & providing me the code!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY
 ,val char(1) NOT NULL
 );

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-----+
| id | val |
+----+-----+
|  1 | b   |
|  2 | b   |
|  3 | b   |
|  4 | b   |
|  5 | b   |
+----+-----+
```